# Unit Testing ICommand and Methods

Tags: c#, wpf, unit-testing, mvvm, icommand

I have developed an WPF application using MVVM as a architecture and am writing some unit tests as part of this. In my view I have a button that is bound to a property in the ViewModel which can be seen below.

**ViewModel**

```
public ICommand MoreInfoCommand
{
    get
    {
        if (_moreInfoCommand == null) 
        {
             _moreInfoCommand = new RelayCommand(parameter => OpenLink());
        }
        return _moreInfoCommand;
    }
}

private void OpenLink() 
{
    try 
    {
         Process.Start("https://www.google.com/");
    }
    catch
    {
      // catch error...
    }
}
```

In my unit testing I have created the following unit test:

**UnitTest**

```
[Description("Test MoreInfoCommand")]
[TestMethod]
public void TestMoreInfoCommand() 
{
     viewModel vm = new viewModel();
     Assert.IsTrue(vm.MoreInfoCommand.CanExecute(null));
}
```

Currently this tests the the property to see if when the button is clicked in the UI the relevant method can be executed. This passes as the conditions are met, however its my understanding I need to test the functionality as well. With this in mind how do I, for example tests that the correct functionality occurs when the button is clicked. I.e how to test what occurs when the ICommand MoreInfoCommand is executed as a result of button click in the UI.

I know private methods can be tested directly, but should in my unit testing I be checking the functionality as well and if so, how can I do this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In your case your command spawns a process, so your unit test can check that the process is running ?

Comment: How would I check in the unit test that the process is running though?

Comment: You don't. You should verify that the method is called only. That's how far the responsibility of the view model that you are testing goes. See my answer for an example of how to this. You need to mock out the call to the static method.

Answer (score 2):

Your view model isn't really testable. If you want to it to be, you should replace the call to the static `Process.Start` method with a call to a method of a interface that you inject the view model with:

```
public ViewModel(IProcessLoader processLoader) =>
    _processLoader = processLoader;

//...

private void OpenLink()
{
    try
    {
        _processLoader.Start("https://www.google.com/");
    }
    catch
    {
        // catch error...
    }
}
```

You could then mock the interface in your unit test, for example using a mocking framwork like [Moq](https://github.com/moq/moq4):

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestMoreInfoCommand()
{
    //Arrange
    Mock<IProcessLoader> processLoader = new Mock<IProcessLoader>();
    viewModel vm = new viewModel(processLoader.Object);
    ICommand command = vm.MoreInfoCommand;

    //Act
    command.Execute(null);

    //Assert
    processLoader.Verify(x => x.Start(It.IsAny<string>()));
}
```

In the real app, you would implement the interface as a wrapper around `Process.Start`:

```
public interface IProcessLoader
{
    void Start(string s);
}

public class ProcessLoader : IProcessLoader
{
    public void Start(string s) => Process.Start(s);
}
```

It's important to realize that you should only verify that the method is called from the view model. A unit test against the view model class should not test the functionality of the `Process` class. The resposibility of the view model ends when `Start` has been called.

.NET and the underlying OS is responsible for what the `Process` class actually does. You should not test this but only your own code.

Comment: @Anonymous: Does this answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

`vm.MoreInfoCommand.CanExecute(null)` would only call the `canExecute` method in your `RelayCommand`, but you did not provide any. `CanExecute` tells nothing about whether `OpenLink` would perform successfully or not.

Although I am no unit test specialist, if your code real looks like this, I doubt if it's worth to write a unit test for it in the first place, because it is so very simple.

As the comment from user auburg states, you can check, whether the process starts, although the process's name would depend on which browser was the standard browser. Also, you would have to wait for some time for the process to start. And maybe there was a process with the same name already running, lots of chances for trouble.

If you really want, you can check, if one of the well known mocking frameworks, e.g. Moq or Rhino Mocks, is able to mock away Process.Start.